# Kendo Grid not updating display correctly

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm working on an application where we are using local storage as our data store based on sample from Kendo Code Library.  We are currently planning on using functions in the datasource to manipulate the data.  You can see that part of our code below.
I have a working sample at http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/fL5UC/2/.

```
 var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
     transport: {
         create: function (options) {
             var localData = JSON.parse(localStorage["grid_data"]);
             localData.push(options.data);
             localStorage["grid_data"] = JSON.stringify(localData);
             options.success(localData);
         },
         read: function (options) {
             var localData = JSON.parse(localStorage["grid_data"]);
             options.success(localData);
         },
         update: function (options) {
             var localData = JSON.parse(localStorage["grid_data"]);
             for (var i = 0; i < localData.length; i++) {
                 if (localData[i].ID == options.data.ID) {
                     localData[i].Value = options.data.Value;
                 }
             }
             localStorage["grid_data"] = JSON.stringify(localData);
             options.success(localData);
             console.log("On update");
             console.log(localData);
         },
         destroy: function (options) {
             var localData = JSON.parse(localStorage["grid_data"]);
             localData.remove(options.data.ID);
             localStorage["grid_data"] = JSON.stringify(localData);
             options.success(localData);
         }
```

To see the problem:

1. Click on "Add New Record".  A new record will appear as the first record in the grid
2. Enter a number in ID column and any text in value column.
3. Click on "Save Changes" button.
4. What was the original first row, will overwrite the newly added row
5. If you click on the JSFiddle run button, then the data will correctly display.

I'm new at using these grids and I don't see what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated below demo.

```
create: function (options) {
                 var localData = JSON.parse(localStorage["grid_data"]);
                 localData.push(options.data);
                 localStorage["grid_data"] = JSON.stringify(localData);
                 options.success(localData);
                 console.log("On create");
                 console.log(localData);
                 $("#grid").data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
             }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fL5UC/3/

Answer (score 1):

When adding a new record to the grid, you need to leave the `ID` field set to its default value (don't let the user edit it), and assign its unique value within the transport's `create` function, which should then provide just the created record as a parameter to `options.success`.  So something like:

```js
 create: function (options) {
     options.data.ID = getNextID();
     var localData = JSON.parse(localStorage["grid_data"]);
     localData.push(options.data);
     localStorage["grid_data"] = JSON.stringify(localData);
     options.success(options.data);
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is because you are calling options.success with the entire dataset as a parameter. For create and update, you only need to return the updated object, as in the options.data object.

```
options.success(options.data);
```

See updated sample  http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/fL5UC/2/

No need to call read on the datasource again, just options.success the updated/created object, and it will act properly.